# Video.js with a small player and controls line breaking

Tags: javascript, css, user-controls, resize, video.js

Just trying to make a smaller player window here. Just wondering what kinds of things I should mess with to make the player display a smaller version of the controls if the window's squished like this:

[image]

Maybe a reduced version of the controls? Smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controls can be customised with CSS. You could add another class to the small player e.g. here I've used `small-player`:

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin small-player" controls
  preload="auto" width="90" height="200" poster="my_video_poster.png"
  data-setup="{}">
  <source src="my_video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
  <source src="my_video.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>
```

Then restyle the controls to suit. For example you could remove the time and resize the big play button:

```
.small-player .vjs-time-controls, .small-player .vjs-time-divider {
  display:none;
}
.small-player .vjs-big-play-button {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;    
}
.small-player .vjs-big-play-button:before {
  font-size:2em;   
  line-height:2;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I started working on something similar. I was just wondering if there was an easier way. But hey, now I don't have to go looking for all of the control elements :V

Comment: You could also try just changing the overall font size to smaller, and see if that does what you need. `.vjs-default-skin { font-size: 5px; }` The control sizes are all based on the main font size through ems.